# Maven Bundle Plugin adding Require-Capability: osgi.ee;filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=9.0))"

Tags: maven, apache-karaf, openapi-generator, maven-bundle-plugin

I'm trying to deploy OpenAPI generated code in Karaf.

Karaf says I need:

```
javax.annotation.meta;version="[3.0,4)"
javax.xml.bind.annotation;version="[2.3,3)"
```

I'm using Java 1.8 to compile, and to run the code.

I'm using `maven-bundle-plugin` v3.5.1

No matter what I do, I end up with this line in my MANIFEST.MF

```
Require-Capability: osgi.ee;filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=9.0))"
```

which I think is possibly the root of the issue.

Is there a way to force Require-Capability to use Java 8?
Or some better workaround?

Comment: are you sure you're using java 1.8 to compile? bndtools (used by maven-bundle plugin) scans all of the classes on the classpath and keeps track of the class file version. This is the default behaviour, you can override it using <_noee>true</_noee> instruction in your maven bundle plugin configuration
</configuration>

Answer (score 3):

bndtools (used by maven-bundle plugin) scans all of the classes on the classpath and keeps track of the class file version.
This is the default behaviour, you can override it using <_noee>true</_noee> instruction in your maven bundle plugin configuration

Comment: Thanks, it didn't fix it, but have an upvote.  I ended up working around it by using the CLI to generate the POJO and API files for CXF+Jackson instead.  The _noee still generated the Java 9 requirement. It seems like the problem has something to do with OkHttp+Gson dependencies, somewhere deep down, but I don't have time to look at it further.  CXF+Jackson probably more simple and reliable anyway.